# online processor in nproc

Tags: osx, cpu

When I run command

```
$ nproc --all
4
```

> DESCRIPTION
>          Print  the  number of processing units available to the current process, which may be less than
>          the number of online processors

It states concepts of `current process` and `online processors`,

if use ps, it output 13 process

```
$ ps | sed '1d' | nl
     1    363 ttys000    0:01.09 -bash
     2  12779 ttys000    0:00.00 sed 1d
     3  12780 ttys000    0:00.00 nl
     4  12781 ttys000    0:00.00 sed s/me/me/g
     5    397 ttys001    0:00.26 -bash
     6  10088 ttys001    0:00.01 man bg
     7  10089 ttys001    0:00.01 sh -c (cd '/usr/share/man' && (echo ".ll 10.2i"; echo ".nr LL 10.2i"; /bin/cat '/usr/share/man/man1/builtin.1') | /usr/bin/tbl | /usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c | (/usr/bin/less -is || true))
     8  10090 ttys001    0:00.01 sh -c (cd '/usr/share/man' && (echo ".ll 10.2i"; echo ".nr LL 10.2i"; /bin/cat '/usr/share/man/man1/builtin.1') | /usr/bin/tbl | /usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c | (/usr/bin/less -is || true))
     9  10095 ttys001    0:00.00 sh -c (cd '/usr/share/man' && (echo ".ll 10.2i"; echo ".nr LL 10.2i"; /bin/cat '/usr/share/man/man1/builtin.1') | /usr/bin/tbl | /usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c | (/usr/bin/less -is || true))
    10  10096 ttys001    0:00.01 /usr/bin/less -is
    11    374 ttys002    0:00.21 -bash
    12    438 ttys003    0:00.28 -bash
    13   9965 ttys003    0:13.74 /Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/me/anaconda3/bin/ipython
```

What does the online processor mean? Does `nproc` have particular usage which could not be substituted by ps

Comment: You seem to be confusing the words "processor" and "process". A processor is a CPU (loosely speaking, not taking hyperthreading into account).  An "online processor" is a processor detected by the OS at boot time. Since you haven't mentioned what OS you are running or how the question relates to `bash` (the tag you have added to it), I'm not turning this into an answer.

Comment: Process — something that is processed, Processor — something that processes [ a process].

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Data is processed, processes as abstract "objects" usually are "processed" only by "meta" tools such as `ps` and the `psmisc` family of tools. And besides the unit of execution is not a process but a thread. Sorry for nitpicking, but when correcting someone's terminology the correction should be, well *correct*. Your definitions of both terms are suboptimal. The question *is* confusing terminology, but it's a valid one and I can see how one comes up with such a question. Can't understand the downvotes to be honest.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I agree.

Comment: oh, OMG, the comment enlighten me, `processes as abstract "objects" usually are "processed" only by "meta" `, so file is also an object.  with this click, I mentally connected  everything. @0xC0000022L could you please transmit the comment to the answer.(comment cannot be searched within stackExchange)

Comment: "And besides the unit of execution is not a process but a thread.?" How could I understand this, thread is a physical existence? I am aware that a running program is a process,  I also learned multiple thread, multipeprocess,

Comment: @Sawajiri you can imagine a process as the container for stuff like file descriptors, memory space and other kernel-provided objects that a process can use. Threads are one such type of objects (not physical, but abstract). And while a process has at least one thread it can have more than one and the CPU in tandem with the kernel takes care of the switching between these units of execution. A thread has its own stack and set of registers, such as the program counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nproc lists the number of CPUs avalable to you.

ps lists the applications currently using those CPUs.

A CPU can be be restricted to a particular user or turned off dynamically for thermal, power or other purposes, making it not available to you.

There are virtual CPUs and other complications (making the terms process and processor more accurate ) but that's the short answer.